# Make a jump line in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Okey, this is the code i have:

```
[lazy_load_box effect="slidefromright" speed="550" delay="80"]
[hero_unit text="Progressive business thinking
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetur" btn_text="soporte 24/7 <br> 123456"   btn_link="http://localhost/wordpress/donec-porta-diam-eu-massa/aliquam-erat-volutpat/" btn_style="primary" btn_size="normal" target="_self"]
[/lazy_load_box]
```

This is part of a code from a wordpress template, i tried to make a jump line here:

```
btn_text="soporte 24/7 <br> 123456"
```

But it doesn´t work it just write in the page:

```
SOPORTE 24/7 <BR> 123456
```

I hope someone know about this. I'm new working with templates.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this line isn't supporting html codes. You should find the html source of this line. So, you can add the br tag after find it.

Comment: haha sometimes a simple few word from other person it's neccesary for solve your problem. Thanks! i just switch the visual to text editor and i see that <br> was another code.